# add edit text value in url

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am doing a project where users can enter the race kart number and it will display corresponding kart's race details. But I am not sure how to add the edit text value to the url in AsyncTask.

code here

```
int kartNumber = Integer.parseInt(etGokart.getText().toString());
.......
 .......
 protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://race.speedtiming.com/api/index.php/races/scoreboard.json?track_id=3");//**-->how to include kart number there in url**
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
..........
..........
}
```

Comment: did you want this  `URL url = new URL("http://race.speedtiming.com/api/index.php/races/scoreboard.json?track_id=3"+kartNumber)`?

Comment: what's the sample URL after adding kartNumber?

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya  I was doing the same but its showing error as file not found exception.

Comment: simply concat your value in url `new URL("http://race.speedtiming.com/api/index.php/races/scoreboard.json?track_id="+kartNumber);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `editText` value to url as below:

```
      int kartNumber = Integer.parseInt(etGokart.getText().toString());
        .......
        .......
         protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
         try {
               URL url = new URL("http://race.speedtiming.com/api/index.php/races/scoreboard.json?track_id="+kartNumber);//**-->how to include kart number there in url**
               HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        ..........
        ..........


   }
```

Comment: Getting java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Comment: @RD87 then check your URL in browser with specific cart number, May be the file is not avaialable there. Are you sure URL is correct and also the Kart Number?

Comment: Ok that makes sense because race is not currently running..Thanks..will try the code when its available

Comment: @RD87 Hope it helped. If yes then you can mark this answer right and upvote so that question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
int kartNumber = Integer.parseInt(etGokart.getText().toString());
String urlWithoutKartNum = "http://race.speedtiming.com/api/index.php/races/scoreboard.json?track_id=#kart_num#";
.......
.......
 protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(urlWithoutKartNum.replace("#kart_num#", kartNumber););//**-->how to include kart number there in url**
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
..........
..........
}
```

Or you can directly append it like:

```
"http://race.speedtiming.com/api/index.php/races/scoreboard.json?track_id="+ kartNmber;
```

Comment: Second one is giving java.io.FileNotFoundException:  ..will try first and update

Comment: I am not sure why 2nd one is giving this exception, it should not be related to url replacing part, it should be somewhere else, can you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

```
int kartNumber = Integer.parseInt(etGokart.getText().toString());
    .......
    .......
     protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
     try {
           String urlText = MessageFormat.format("http://race.speedtiming.com/api/index.php/races/scoreboard.json?track_id={0}", kartNumber);
           URL url = new URL(urlText);
           HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    ..........
    ..........
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of the code you've presented. A code-only answer does little to help the person who asked the question.